# how to block a user from publishing a node in drupal 7

Tags: users, nodes, blocks

Please tell me that the user creates a node and he or she cannot publish that node on website and administrator can review that node and then the administer publish that node....

Answer (score 1):

There is [workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module which suits your requirement.

> The workflow module allows the creation and assignment of arbitrary workflows to Drupal node types. Workflows are made up of workflow states. For example, a workflow with the states Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type.

Answer (score 1):

consider using the [workbench module suite](http://drupal.org/project/workbench)
it gives you full control who can do what, and introduces states, like needs review.

with the [publish content module](http://drupal.org/project/publishcontent) you have a simpler approach. only permissions.